# How to print on a Yosemite managed printer from a Panther Mac?

Tags: network, macos, printing, cups, panther

A couple I know have two computers I'm supporting - one is a iMac which I recently upgraded from Snow Leopard (10.6) to Yosemite (10.10).  The printer is attached to this machine.  The other computer, unfortunately, is a 450MHz [Power Mac G4 (AGP graphics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Mac_G4) running the last version of Panther (10.3.9).  Surprisingly, the 14-year-old computer still works and is actively being used (primarily for [AppleWorks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleWorks#AppleWorks.2FClarisWorks_.28Macintosh.2FWindows_versions.2C_1991.E2.80.932004.29) documents, which is another "ugh").

Before the iMac was upgraded, I had done *something* to it which let the Power Mac see the shared printer.  I suspect it had to do with [CUPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS), but I could be wrong.  Ever since the upgrade to Yosemite, the Power Mac has been unable to print, and I can't seem to recreate the old setup.

My question resumed in one sentence is:

**How do I share a printer *from* a Mac running Yosemite *to* one running Panther, so that the Panther one can print?**

Comment: both need Bonjour/Rendezvous running. Yosemite needs discoveryd to not be blocked on the firewall.

Comment: I would assume that turning on printer sharing would take care of that.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Enabling Printer Sharing and sharing the printer - System Prefs->Sharing, and System Prefs-> Print & Scan, respectively - on the iMac should let the G4 see and use the printer. CUPS would provide the driver if you don't have the printer-specific driver installed on either machine.

Comment: @douggro - Update: I tried exactly that and even with the printer driver installed, it couldn't see it.  I was just going to "Add Printer" from the printer menu, which seemed like the correct place.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you may have to go that route, i.e. adding the printer manually. The Bonjour shared printer auto-discovery was added in Leopard or Snow Leopard (can't remember which - I know it works in SnowLep)

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I hit a ≠ problem but which might help to figure out a more general problem. I have a network conf. described in this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/188399/22003 . `Alice` & `Bob` were both running Mountain lion (10.8) and `Printer Sharing` was used. Since I upgraded Bob to Yosemite (10.10) `Printer Sharing` is not anymore working. Since I am hunting the origin of the problem.

Comment: Could you add the output of `ifconfig en1` on your Panther Mac?
I am now convinced that `Bonjour` is broken on Yosemite above IPv4, and pretty sure that Panther doesn't talk IPv6.

Comment: @danielAzuelos - Sorry, I never did get it working.  I'll give it a try the next time I'm over their house and add the output.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity I will name your Power Mac G4 running Panther: `Pant` and your iMac running Yosemite: `Yose`.

`Yosemite` has problem to print in an IPv4 environment (see: [How to make shared printing works on Yosemite within an IPv4 only network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/188399/22003).
On the other hand `Panther` is able to run `IPv6`.

### Check IPv6

Hence the 1rst point to check to be able to print from `Pant` is that Ipv6 is up and running. If `Pant` and `Yose` are connected through Ethernet, you will check this with (this is a command to enter within `Terminal`):

```
ifconfig en0
```

and you should get an output containing a line starting as:

```
inet6 fe80::
```

Which prooves that `Pant` has an IPv6 address and is IPv6 connected.
If they are connected through AirPort, you have to check the same output with:

```
ifconfig en1
```

If `Pant` doesn't have an IPv6 address, you will have to modify its network configuration through:

```
System Preferences > Network
```

select `Advanced...`
and under the `TCP/IP` window, select

```
Configure IPv6: Automatically
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>Apply</kbd>.
Check that IPv6 is now up and running.

### Check cupsd

If you just enabled IPv6 for the 1st time on `Pant` then you will have to restart `cupsd` so that it will be able to talk this protocol.

The easiest way is to simply restart `Pant`. (But if you prefer to understand what you modify clearly, to restart `cupsd` is sufficient).

You will now have to check that `cupsd` is able to talk IPv6. (If I would had a Panther running Mac at hand I would have answered directly, but I don't).

Here are the command to type within `Terminal` to perform this checking:

```
ps ax | egrep '[ /](PID|cupsd)'
```

will display you 2 lines as:

```
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
76864   ??  Ss     0:00.26 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
```

where the number `PID` is the proces id of the `cupsd` daemon.

Use this process id (here 76864) to check if this daemon is talking IPv6 through the help of `lsof` as follows:

```
/usr/bin/sudo lsof -p 76864 | egrep '(COMMAND|IPv)'
```

This is a priviledged command, hence you have to use `sudo` which will
ask you your user password.
This command should give you an output very similar to:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD     TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
cupsd   76864 root    9u    IPv4 0x9007abdfc3bf58ad       0t0       TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
cupsd   76864 root   15u    IPv6 0x9007abdfb88bf0cd       0t0       TCP localhost:ipp (LISTEN)
```

If you have a line where `TYPE` == `IPv6` then the `cupsd` on `Pant` is talking IPv6.

### Restart the sharing

If you just enabled IPv6 for the 1st time on `Pant` then you will have
to enable from fresh the sharing on `Yose` so that `Pant` will see it correctly through the IPv6 channel.

On `Yose` open

```
System Preferences > Sharing
```

stop `Printer Sharing`, wait for `Printer Sharing: Off` to display, and restart it.

On `Pant` add a new printer, and you should see a new one to add and configure on `Yose`.

### Disclaimer

This is a blind receipe (I don't have a Panther to fully check it).
I tried to avoid at most dangerous modifications on MacOS.

Any feedback would be appreciated to improve this draft answer.