# How to make shared printing works on Yosemite within an IPv4 only network?

Tags: macos, printing, network, cups

### Network landscape

My network is made through Internet Sharing from a Mac: `Bob` hosting an USB printer: `Clara`. On this home network is a Mac: `Alice` which is usually printing on `Clara` through `Bob`.

```
Alice    --AirPort--    Bob    --Ethernet--    Internet
Mac                     Mac
10.0.2.23       10.0.2.1    192.168.1.1
                         |
                        USB
                         |
                        Clara
                        printer
```

Of course, on `Bob` the `Firewall` is on, and the sharing of `Clara` is on.

One key detail: this problem of shared printing failing occured when I upgraded `Bob` from Mountain Lion to **Yosemite**.

### Bug

For security reasons (don't let open what you don't fully control), I stop any IPv6 on the internal side of my network.

On both `Alice`, `Bob` I ran:

```
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
```

Since this modification my network is working perfectly (and in fact much better). `Alice` can access the Internet with `ssh`, `http`, `IMAP`, `smtp`… without a glitch, but for printing.

`Alice` does still see `Clara` as a shared printer, but printing dosen't work, and the printer window stays on the message:

```
Printing - Looking for printer
```

forever. The `CUPS` error log does says:

```
E [23/May/2015:11:05:50 +0200] [Job 621] Unable to find printer.
```

If on `Alice` I check the reachability of `CUPS` on `Bob`
I get:

```
alice$ telnet 10.0.2.1 631
Trying 10.0.2.1...
Connected to bob.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Hence `CUPS` is running on `Bob` and perfectly reachable through IPv4.

If I turn IPv6 back on, shared printing is working again.
The firewall isn't involved in this network problem.

### Question

How may I get shared printing to work on an IPv4 only network?

I already found this correct analysis of a similar problem on Linux:
[Disabling IPv6 seems to break CUPS](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/disabling-ipv6-seems-to-break-cups-4175518566/)

But the suggested modification to the `cupsd.conf` 
framed with the relevant `launchctl stop... launchctl start`
doesn't fix it.

Moreover I discovered that I have to be cautious on tuning:

```
/etc/cups/cupsd.conf
```

because `Printer Sharing` activation is overwriting this configuration file.